# Passing characters as argument into db function in R

Tags: sql, r, odbc

I am wondering how to pass 2 *characters* `(x,y)` in my below **R** `user-defined function`, and hope someone could assist on this:

```
sql.r<-function(x,y){

# Load RODBC package
library(RODBC)

# Create a connection to the database called "con"
con <- odbcConnect("odbccalc", uid=xxx, pwd=xxx, believeNRows=FALSE)

# Check that connection is working (Optional)
odbcGetInfo(con)

# Find out what tables are available (Optional)
Tables <- sqlTables(con, schema="tblData")

# Query the database and put the results into the data frame "dataframe"
dataframe <- sqlQuery(con, "
                    SELECT lbl,Date, dot
                    FROM
                    tblData t
                    WHERE t.lbl="'',x,"''
                    AND t.Date <"'',y,"''
                    ORDER BY t.Date desc")
```

The syntax problem might lie in the management of `quotes`.

*Working syntax, in case it helps*:

```
sqlQuery(con, "
                  SELECT lbl,Date, dot
                  FROM
                  tblData t
                  WHERE t.lbl='fruit'
                  AND   t.Date < '2015-06-01'
                  ORDER BY t.Date desc")
```

Best,

Comment: Use `paste` to build the query. See `?paste`.

Comment: @nicola: do not see the point following a check, as in `Matlab` i usually handle the quotes within the `sql` statements. I am just not sure for `R`.

Comment: @nrussell: if you also insist on it, both of you might have right. ps: are you aware of some documentation where  any `sql syntax` in conjunction `paste` have been illustrated? I am googling it...

Comment: The point is that `sqlQuery` takes two args: a connection and a string. The string is the sql command you want to execute. If the command depends on some inputs, you have to build the string accordingly. `paste` and `sprintf` let you do this. You are putting the values of the `x` and `y` variables in the string representing the command. This isn't sql specific, but just standard string manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others say, you can use `paste` or `paste0` to construct the query. However, the `sprintf` function can also do the trick. I think this is slightly more easy to read as you avoid mixed single and double quotation marks.

I.e. do something like the following in your function:

```
query <- sprintf("SELECT lbl, Date, dot
                 FROM
                 tblData t
                 WHERE t.lbl= '%s'
                 AND   t.Date < '%s'
                 ORDER BY t.Date desc", x, y)
sqlQuery(con, query)
```

Comment: i agree the syntax it's slightly easier for on the reading side. However `lbl` object  is not found. ps: in my table `lbl` is set as `nvarchar`

Comment: The variable `query` is just a character string in R which happen to contain an SQL query. So, you should change `lbl` (which is "hardcoded" into the string") is to whatever it needs to be. If is not found, your constructed query is wrong. Unfortunately, I'm not particular familiar with SQL, so I can't help you there.

Comment: You've already done much, and I do thank you for the time you've devoted to my tread. I've checked my query before asking any question on this site (`= strict minimum` I could do, and nothing went wrong with it). However undesired `typos` from my side while testing (copying and pasting) your block of codes have created such a `misunderstanding`. Apologies for that and one more time, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to build the query through `paste` or `paste0`. Try this:

```
 dataframe <- sqlQuery(con, paste0("
                SELECT lbl,Date, dot
                FROM
                tblData t
                WHERE t.lbl='",x,"'
                AND t.Date <'",y,"'
                ORDER BY t.Date desc"))
```

The point is that `sqlQuery` takes two args: a `connection` and a string. The string is the `sql` command you want to execute. If the command depends on some inputs, you have to build the string accordingly. `paste` and `sprintf` let you do this. You are putting the values of the `x` and `y` variables in the string representing the command. This isn't sql specific, but just standard string manipulation.

Comment: Also, think about whether you want to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.  If your database is well managed, it may not be necessary.

Comment: @nicola: no error on the running side, so thanks. However and surprisingly it does not retrieve `dataframe`.

Comment: @nicola: update from my previous comments (please forget about it...). your syntax with `paste0` works up to `AND t.Date <'",y,"'` . As a matter of fact this condition is not fullfiled and to illustrate the phenomenon: the query still outputs the whole dataset up to `T` despite I specify `y<T`. just `weird`, fyi

Comment: What's wrong in `still outputs the whole dataset up to T` when you `specify y<T`? It's not exactly what you specified? However, it's not a problem of syntax anymore: you have to adjust your query to get your desired results.

Comment: @nicola: silly `typos` from my side, while carrying multiple tasks at the same time . Apologies, and I do confirm that all is working perfectly. Thank You Very Much!!!